# Android View Extends Class Force Close Error

Tags: android

I am working Drawing Application. I am Draw View Class Extends View for Drawing Below For 
Draw.java class:

```
package com.draw;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;

import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class DrawView extends View implements OnTouchListener {
    private Canvas  mCanvas;
    private Path    mPath;
    private Paint       mPaint;   
    private ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
    private ArrayList<Path> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Path>(); 

    private Bitmap im;
    public DrawView(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);      
        this.setOnTouchListener(this);
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(6);
        mCanvas = new Canvas();
        mPath = new Path();
        paths.add(mPath);

        im=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);


    }               
        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {            

            for (Path p : paths){
                canvas.drawPath(p, mPaint);
            }
        }

        private float mX, mY;
        private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

        private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
            mPath.reset();
            mPath.moveTo(x, y);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
        private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
            float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
            float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
            if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
                mX = x;
                mY = y;
            }
        }
        private void touch_up() {
            mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
            // commit the path to our offscreen
            mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
            // kill this so we don't double draw            
            mPath = new Path();
            paths.add(mPath);
        }

        public void onClickUndo () { 
            if (paths.size()>0) 
            { 
               undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size()-1));
               invalidate();
             }
            else
            {

            }
             //toast the user 
        }

        public void onClickRedo (){
           if (undonePaths.size()>0) 
           { 
               paths.add(undonePaths.remove(undonePaths.size()-1)); 
               invalidate();
           } 
           else 
           {

           }
             //toast the user 
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
          float x = event.getX();
          float y = event.getY();

          switch (event.getAction()) {
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                  touch_start(x, y);
                  invalidate();
                  break;
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                  touch_move(x, y);
                  invalidate();
                  break;
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                  touch_up();
                  invalidate();
                  break;
          }
          return true;
    }
}
```

And I am mentioned my layout below :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <com.draw.DrawView
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
             />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Undo" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Redo" />

    </RelativeLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

And My Activity Class Code Below:

```
package com.draw;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Draw extends Activity {
    DrawView draw_view ;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //drawView = new DrawView(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //drawView.requestFocus();
        try
        {
         draw_view=(DrawView) findViewById(R.id.view1);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(),4000).show();
        }
        Button btn_undo=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn_undo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                draw_view.onClickUndo();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Xml Load Error Occured in Logcat

```
05-15 16:27:01.407: E/AndroidRuntime(1064): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.draw/com.draw.Draw}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class com.draw.DrawView
```

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: So what is the problem that you are seeing? 
Try to use logcat http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html to retrieve the full stacktrace. This will give you a hint on your problem. If that doesn't help you add it to the question and we may spot the problem in the code.

Comment: Have you tried changing the values on line 13 in the xml document?